# GridLayout isn't fully visible while scrolling left

Tags: android, scrollview, grid-layout

I'm trying to do "Minesweeper". Basically I have `GridLayout` inside `ScrollView` and `HorizontalScrollView`. Everything is OK if all fields are on screen (in my case `ImageButtons`). But if I zoom in (increase size of `ImageButtons`), `HorizontalScrollView` works just partly.

**Take a look at this pics:**
[image]

More I zoom in more fields are hidden on the left side and more free space is on right side.

**XML layout:**

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center" >

        </GridLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</ScrollView>
```

**And how I add buttons dynamically to GridLayout:**

```
field = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        field.setColumnCount(N);
        field.setRowCount(N);


        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
                ImageButton b = new ImageButton(this);
                b.setId(j*10+i);
                b.setImageResource(R.drawable.unknowen);
                b.setTag(R.drawable.unknowen);
                b.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                b.setPadding(5,5,5,5);

                GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
                params.setMargins(-7,-7,-7,-7);
                params.width = fieldSize;
                params.height = fieldSize;

                b.setOnClickListener(this);
                b.setOnLongClickListener(this);
                field.addView(b, params);
            }
        }
```

I apologize for bad language, and thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm pretty sure nesting a GridView (which implements scroll listening) inside a HorizontalScrollView (which also implements scroll listening) isn't likely to work as expected.

But, if you're doing horizontal scrolling only, you may want to just add android:scrollbars="horizontal" to the GridView and get rid of the HorizontalScrollView entirely (but I'm not sure if you also require vertical scrolling, which would cause this answer to give more problems).

As for adding data to the GridView, you should be changing the data in the LIST of objects the GridView's Adapter is backed by; not the actual View itself. The Views inside the GridView are generated as-needed by the Adapter and are populated in the Adapter's override-able getView() method by mapping the position in the View with the position in your dataset.

Also note, after changing the dataset, you MUST ALWAYS call notifyDataSetChanged() on the Adapter in order for it to refresh its View's with the updated result.

Comment: Yes I need vertical and horizontal scroll. So do you think should I use GridView instead of GridLayout?

Comment: For your scenario it probably wouldn't make much difference between the two, but either way you're looking at a situation where you need both horizontal and vertical scrolling, which means you're very likely going to have to extend your View/Adapter choice to handle the scrolling yourself

Comment: So I should programatically add or remove View from List?

Comment: Not the View; the data in which your View is populated by

Comment: I mean `ImageButtons`, isn't they instance of View class?

Comment: Yes, but you're not adding that directly. You have to change the DATA in the array that backs your Adapter, and the Adapter will handle the View population in it's getView() method after you call notifyDataSetChanged()